# What does a manifold which is a solution to a set of $n$ affine equations look like?

Tags: linear-algebra, manifolds

I was reading a paper by Duffie and Kan where they mention that the solution to $a_{ii}+b_{ii}.x=0, i=1 \text{ to } n$ is an $(n-1)$ dimensional manifold. I have never studied manifolds and if you could point me to a source which could help me get just the basic intuitive understanding it would be very helpful(In particular this sort of manifold)

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold) for manifolds, with several examples. Finite-dimensional real vector spaces are manifolds.

Answer (score 1):

My impression is it's just like a vector space, except that it doesn't have to contain the zero vector.   So any translation of a vector space. That is, take a vector space,  $V$, and consider all sums $v+w$, for $v\in V$ and some vector $w\not\in V$.

For manifolds there are many sources.  I like Spivak, for instance.